How can I run StableDiffusion with keras_cv, keras 3?
I'm trying to generate Image with keras_cv StableDiffusion in Google Colab. I started with tutorial code, but it doesn't work. Here's my code :

packages install

!pip install tensorflow keras_cv --upgrade --quiet
!apt install --allow-change-held-packages libcudnn8=8.1.0.77-1+cuda11.2


import packages

import time
import keras_cv
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


get StableDiffusion model

keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy("mixed_float16")
model = keras_cv.models.StableDiffusion(jit_compile=True)


generate image

gen_image = model.text_to_image(
    "photograph of an astronaut riding unicorn",
    batch_size=3,
)


Error Message

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-703d417859ee> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 # 주어진 텍스트로 이미지를 생성합니다.
      2 
----> 3 gen_image = model.text_to_image(
      4     "photograph of an astronaut riding unicorn",
      5     batch_size=3,

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py in _adjust_input_rank(self, flat_inputs)
    242                     adjusted.append(ops.expand_dims(x, axis=-1))
    243                     continue
--> 244             raise ValueError(
    245                 f"Invalid input shape for input {x}. Expected shape "
    246                 f"{ref_shape}, but input has incompatible shape {x.shape}"

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling DiffusionModel.call().

Invalid input shape for input Tensor("data_2:0", shape=(3, 77, 768), dtype=float16). Expected shape (None, 64, 64, 4), but input has incompatible shape (3, 77, 768)

Arguments received by DiffusionModel.call():
  • inputs={'latent': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(3, 64, 64, 4), dtype=float32)', 'timestep_embedding': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(3, 320), dtype=float32)', 'context': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(3, 77, 768), dtype=float16)'}
  • training=False
  • mask={'latent': 'None', 'timestep_embedding': 'None', 'context': 'None'}

I think it's because content(aka. prompt) is going to latent input parameter. However, any clue?
